# I only have one user in my linux operating system and I've removed him from the sudoers group. Now how to access Root?

Tags: sudo, root, users

Consider a single user(with a root user) where the user doesn't know the password of the root user which disables him from using `su root` and who was in sudoers file but he himself removed him from the sudoers group with the command`sudo adduser foo sudo`.
Now, How does the user foo will access root privileges?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've locked yourself out of `sudo` privileges. You are going to need to boot to Grub recovery mode and access root shell.

1. Go to Grub menu by pressing `shift` key upon startup.
2. Select `Ubuntu recovery mode` and then `root shell prompt`
3. Type in:

   ```
   mount -o rw,remount /
   ```

   and in the next line

   ```
   usermod -aG sudo username
   ```

   where username is your username.
4. Exit and restart.
5. Check the `/etc/group` file. Your username should now be in the `sudo` group.

As long as your user is in the `sudo` group, `Sudoers` file may be modified to give privileges to access root with `sudo su` command, providing that you know user's password.